# Looking for the media equivalent of "televised"

Tags: word-choice, analogy

If you say "an event has been televised", it means that the event has been recorded for or transmitted by television.

Media covers not only television, but also radio, newspapers and the Internet.

What is the equivalent of "televised" for the more generic term of media?

The best I can think of is "an event has been media-ised". Is there a better (or more correct) word for this?

Comment: The generic term is "***broadcast***", or, in media jargon, "*put on the wire*".

Comment: @DanBron please add that as an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if [this article](http://www.greythinking.com/2011/06/11/medialization-and-a-catch-22/) is using the medical definition of *medialization*, yours, both or a new one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a one-word equivalent that's broader in scope than ***televised***, I would try ***covered***.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/coverage

Comment: Please provide a definition and possibly an online dictionary link to the term you are suggesting.

Comment: Note that when you say "the event was *televised*" you're specifically talking about live coverage - i.e. you can see the event live as it happens by watching the broadcast. "Covered" can be live or not-live. Note that some media like newspapers (whether printed or online) do not support the concept of live coverage due to their nature.  You can also say "covered live" for media which support this concept but which may or may not be live, e.g. "The event was *covered live* via twitter."

Answer (score 5):

It originated with print media, but [*publish*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publish) can easily be used in a broader context:

> 1 a :  to make generally known
>   b :  to make public announcement of
>
> 2
>   a :  to disseminate to the public
>   b :  to produce or release for distribution; specifically :  print 2c
>   c :  to issue the work of (an author)
>   <sub>source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publish</sub>

Or, as Dan Bron points out, you can go a little father back up the etymological chain, and use *[publicize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publicize)*:

> : to cause (something) to be publicly known : to give information about (something) to the public
>   <sub>source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/publicize</sub>

Comment: Or, going back to the word's roots, maybe even *publicized*.

Comment: @DanBron, an excellent suggestion!  I will edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

We use the expressions:

"It's been in the media."
"It's all over the media."
"It's forefront in the media." (US)

Comment: Also, *in the press*.

Answer (score 1):

The general term for "*reported by the media*" (other than *reported*, and its non-media-specific synonyms, of course) is "***broadcast***".

From the American Heritage Dictionary ([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=broadcast)) entry

> **broadcast**:
>
> 1. To communicate or transmit (a signal, a message, or content, such as audio or video programming) to numerous recipients simultaneously over a communication network: *a radio station that broadcasts news; an agency broadcasting an appeal for donations over the Internet.*
> 2. To make known over a wide area: *reporters who broadcast unchecked rumors in order to get the story out first*; "*The birds sang in flight because that was the only way, in this treeless terrain, to broadcast their claims across their chosen pieces of land*" (Kenn Kaufman).
>
> See synonyms at **[announce](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=A5332900)**.

The word is abstract, and can be used for any kind of conspicuous announcement to the general public or any large audience. In recent decades, it is more often associated with radio, television, and the internet, but is has and continues to be used of print journalism as well.

For example, from an issue of "*The Nineteenth Century and After*" published in 1916, when newspapers were the dominant form of journalism, radio was not yet popular, and TV hadn't even been invented, [Fernand Passelecq wrote](https://books.google.com/books?id=tJI6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA705&dq=%22broadcast%20in%20the%20papers%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=M1UyVfi3KveasQTr1ICAAg&ved=0CCgQuwUwAA):

> ### Belgian Unity and the Flemish Movement
>
> ⋯
>
> *As soon as their works were published their conclusions were **broadcast in the papers**, from the beginning of 1915 onwards, by a legion of publicists writing thousands of articles on the subject. It is a methodic action, somewhat ...*

In media jargon, there is also the phrase "*put on [the wire](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/189201/55623)*".

---

Bonus fact of the day: when I looked this word up in order to have a dictionary to reference in this answer, I learned that *broadcast* came from the practice of sowing a field by *casting* seeds out over a *broad* area (as opposed to carefully dropping them in a line along a furrough, I suppose).

Comment: *Broadcast* is a good term for TV and radio but not for newspapers reporting something.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Not quite true; I have updated my answer to address this concern, however.

Answer (score 1):

[This discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media) describes one popular means of “**delivering** media” (streaming) and makes multiple references to ‘streaming’ as one kind of “**delivery** method [of media].” The discussion's repeated use of multiple forms of the generic word “deliver” in this context leads me to propose “[delivered](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deliver)” as a possible alternative to use in place of your clever “media-ised”:

> The Final Four Games were delivered by TBS, TNT and TruTV; and the Championship Game by CBS.

Other generic verbs similar to “delivered” used in the linked discussion of ‘streaming’ include “[presented](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/present),” “[distributed](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/distribute),” and (contained in your question) “[transmitted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transmit),” all of which are, in my opinion, media-relevant while being media-type neutral, and as such could also replace “media-ised .”

Answer (score 0):

**to air**

is quite general

> **air**
>
> transitive v.
>
> 2 b :  to expose for the sake of public notice :  make open to the
>   public
>
> *he did not air his politics in the pulpit — K. B. Murdock*
>
> *the issue will be thoroughly aired — Newsweek*
>
> 3 :  to transmit by radio or television :  broadcast
>
> *programs which will be aired in the future — Musical Digest*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

E.g.,

> Billboard - 27 Nov 1999 - Page 64 Vol. 111, No. 48 - ‎Magazine
>
> **The event was aired** live on MTV Europe and was also broadcast later the same night with a taped delay on the UK's terrestrial TV
>   network ITV and on Ireland's national terrestrial network RTE.